# SFDX unlocked package error for recordtypes

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I have case object in my unlocked package. While versioning of case object I am getting errors for reacordtypes.
"case.recordtype name" Case.Recordtype name: 
duplicate value found:  is a duplicate of the value in the record with the following ID: >

Note:There is no inactive/duplicate values for picklist in org.

Not getting proper solution for this. What could be the issue?